# Unable to find my robot with an error

Tags: gazebo

[This question](https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/20229/gazebo-does-not-load-simple-model/) and the [docs](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=components&cat=get_started) pointed me to `$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` as being the environment variable to change to include models in a gazebo world. However, I am getting an error.

This is my current tree structure:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── model
│   └── robot
│       ├── model.config
│       └── model.sdf
├── script
│   └── hello.cpp
└── worlds
    ├── empty.world
    └── myworld
```

My `GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` is:

```
$ $ echo $GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH
:/home/self/workspace/build_my_world/model/robot:
```

But when I run gazebo I get an error.

```
$ gazebo worlds/myworld 
Error [parser.cc:652] Could not find model.config or manifest.xml for the model
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
```

This is what I have in `myworld` file:

```
   1 <sdf version='1.6'>
   2   <world name='default'>
   3     
   4     <include>
   5       <pose frame=''>0 0 30 0 0 0</pose>
   6       <uri>model://model</uri>
   7     </include>
   8
```

The final problem is that even if I remove the model in the world file, entering `gazebo` doesn't launch the application. There's NO output either.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should add to `$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH` the base directory of your model collection, `/home/self/workspace/build_my_world/model`.

Second, you should refer to your model by the name of its subdirectory, `robot` in this case.

Third, you should close the `<world>` and `<sdf>` tags at the end of the file.

It's also advisable to add the `sun` and `ground_plane` models to your world.

So in summary, what you should have is the following:

```
$ echo $GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH
:/home/self/workspace/build_my_world/model
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sdf version='1.6'>
  <world name='default'>
    <include>
      <uri>model://sun</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
      <uri>model://ground_plane</uri>
    </include>
    <include>
      <pose frame=''>0 0 0 0 0 0</pose>
      <uri>model://robot</uri>
    </include>
  </world>
</sdf>
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that I truncated the world file. It is over 3000 lines long.

Comment: Is the colon `:` still part of the `$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH`? Running `gazebo` still doesn't do anything.

Comment: It is, but more importantly, you must make sure that Gazebo is reading the variable. Are you launching it from the same session where you `export`ed it?

Comment: I thought so but I can't check now since I restarted the virtual machine. I also realized that there was a bash variable that wasn't set to anything so the path had two `//` where a directory needed to have been included.

Comment: I thought so but I can't check now since I restarted the virtual machine. I also realized that by doing the export in the `.bashrc` that there was a bash variable that wasn't set to anything so the path had two `//` where I expected `/build_my_world/`. I `source`d `.bashrc` and I didn't see the missing directory when I `echo`ed.

Comment: If you can publish your current work somewhere we can download it that would make it easier to find the issue.

Comment: https://github.com/here2infinity/build_my_world/tree/attempt-1

Comment: I added my repo. I still can't see the robot though but gazebo is running on `myworld`.

Comment: The problem is that in your `myworld` file you have several models named `robot`. Remove or rename them to e.g. `robot_2`, `robot_3` etc. and you'll see the `<include>`d model. You can also try the simplified world in my answer, that will work as well. One last remark, the initial pose `<pose frame=''>0 0 30 0 0 0</pose>` instantiates the robot $30 m$ above ground, you may want to reassess that.

Comment: I put the robot 30 *m* above the ground so that I wouldn't be confused by the other models on the floor plan. It was just meant as a test.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to mess things up editing .bashrc variables, I suggest you to use `gazebo_ros`, and you can edit `package.xml` file to tell gazebo to where to look for models. A simple example would be;

````
<depend>gazebo_ros</depend>

<export>
      <gazebo_ros gazebo_model_path="${prefix}/models"/>
      <gazebo_ros gazebo_media_path="${prefix}/worlds"/>
</export>```
````